# ValueError: Input strings must be a multiple of 16 in length error on decryption of encrypted data in python 2.7 for AES

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, aes

I need help! 
I'm using AES for data encryption in my python project.Using a method below named `encrypt` I can encrypt data.This method works and i can save encrypted data on database .I'm using mongodb.
My problem is when I try to decrypt those data.Below is written a query. I tested it returns data in json format.

```
patient_data = mongo.db.patients.find_one({'_id': doc_id})
doc = decrypt(patient_data)
```

Parameter `patient_data` is a json. When i use decrypt method and I run my project I have the error below:

[image: Error]

I added the code how I did AES encrytion/decryption

```
key=b'\xbf\xc0\x85)\x10nc\x94\x02)j\xdf\xcb\xc4\x94\x9d(\x9e[EX\xc8\xd5\xbfI{\xa2$\x05(\xd5\x18'
    cipher = AES.new(key)

    def pad(s):
        return s + ((16-len(s) % 16) * '{')

    def encrypt(patient_data):
        global cipher
        for d in patient_data:
            encoded=cipher.encrypt(pad(patient_data[d]))
            encoded = b64encode(encoded) 
            patient_data_encrypted = patient_data
            patient_data_encrypted[d] = encoded
            # decode the encoded string
        return patient_data_encrypted

    def decrypt(patient_data):
        global cipher
        for d in patient_data:
            patient_data = b64decode(patient_data[d])
            dec = cipher.decrypt(patient_data).decode('utf8')
            l = dec.count('{')
            decoded = dec[:len(dec)-l]
            patient_data_dencrypted = patient_data
            patient_data_dencrypted[d] = decoded
        return patient_data_dencrypted


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mj4VL.png
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to be doing this in the decrypt: patient_data = b64decode(patient_data[d])?

Comment: Yes , in the end of the encryption method after encryption I encoded data encoded = b64encode(encoded) , so the first thing before decryption should be decoding patient data = b64decode(patient data[d]) , so any idea? @dbugger

Comment: you seem to be overwriting the patient_data you passed into the function.

Comment: Check the length of your cyphertext before you post to the database. Is it a multiple of 16 bytes? Check the length again when you retrieve it from the database.  Has the length changed?  Your error message can often be caused by a change in data length.